# Notation $\sin^2hx$ vs $\sinh^2x$

Tags: notation

I used to write $\sin^2hx$ every time I wanted to show $(\sinh x)^2$.But I saw the notation $\sinh^2x$ somewhere and I thought the correct notation for this, is $\sinh^2x$ because we have the function $\sinh()$ and if I want to square it, the number $2$ should be above "h". Am I right? and using the notation $\sin^2hx$  for $(\sinh x)^2$ is incorrect?

Comment: $\sin^2 \, hx$ is wrong notation to use for square of $\sinh$ function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\sin^2hx$ it's $\sin^2(hx)$ or $(\sin(hx))^2$, while
$\sinh^2x=(\sinh{x})^2$